# How did domain events become part of DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

Domain events are not described in the famous blue DDD book. When and how did they become part of the domain-driven design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eric Evans: *What I've learned about DDD since the book*

- [QCon 2009 Slides](https://qconlondon.com/london-2009/qconlondon.com/dl/qcon-london-2009/slides/EricEvans_WhatIveLearnedAboutDDDSinceTheBook.pdf)
- [2012 Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lE6Hxz4yomA&t=12m25s)

Answer (score 2):

Domain events express facts that happen in the domain and thus are **first class citizens** of the domain so there are very very important from the DDD point of view.

Even more, when interfacing with another bounded context, they could represent **the contract** between the two bounded contexts.

P.S. they are covered by the "[red DDD book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321834577)" in chapter 8.

Comment: This book is rather new

Comment: I will. Some day.